# c# send hex via tcp

Tags: c#, tcp, hex

I am trying to send hex data via TCP.

I know how to do it in UDP but TCP just isn't working for me:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.202", 8000);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

ASCIIEncoding Enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] s = new byte[] { 0xa5, 0x5b, 0x02, 0x03, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07 };
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
```

Comment: you are right, i've pasted the wrong code. i've edited and tis is the non working code. the error is that the command it sent in wrong format.

Comment: I don't see a sending command. Where do you try to send the byte array? Could you please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know how to add the sending command, I'm searching for an example for hours, thats why i'm here

Comment: Console.WriteLine("0x" + s.ToString("x2"));

Comment: If you need to send a string in that represents Hex values, you can try soemthing like this: `string.Join(" ", s.Select(bTs => bTs.ToString("X2")));`. But, are you sure you need a string and not a byte array?

Comment: I need to send byte array, not string.

Comment: `ASCIIEncoding` is a string-related class. This: `0xa5` and this: `165` are the same values. *trying to send hex data via TCP* what does this mean? You have a byte array; the byte value espression you use is irrelevant. It's quite unclear what values you need to send. If you want to send a string represented as a byte array, then use `byte[] MyStringInBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MyString);`. This depends on the string composition, though. Maybe you want byte[] `MyStringInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyString);` istead. If your string is in encoded in Unicode. Or `.Unicode.GetBytes()`.

Answer (score 0):

i've solved it like this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.202", 8000);

        Byte[] s = new byte[] { 0xa5, 0x5b, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf9 };
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(s, 0, s.Length);
```